# Can one configure Chrome to offer opening downloads in suitable applications?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently made Google Chrome my default browser (mainly due to its bookmark and preferences syncing capabilities across multiple systems).

One thing I find increasingly annoying with it though is, that Chrome does not allow to directly open a downloaded file in an appropriate application!

In IE I was us to, that, when I clicked onto a link pointing to some document, e.g. a spreadsheet, to being asked, whether I wanted to save this document to a local file or to directly open it (in Excel in this example). This worked with all kinds of registered applications but also other formats, e.g. email addresses (mailto:-links) or Calendar entries (.ics-files) which directly opened Outlook's new email dialog with the email-address already filled int or created a new calendar entry from the .ics file, resp.

In Chrome one can only save such docs to a local file and then needs to locate that and has to open it manually. I find this always most cumbersome! Is there some plugin that allows to bring back the convenience I was used to?

And to spare me the usual comments on such feature requests right away: Yes, I am aware, that this is a potential security issue, if one opens docs from dubious sources, etc. I know, that one needs to understand what one is doing in such situations, but I think I do!

Answer (score 0):

Click the little arrow beside the file, which is being downloaded and choose `Always open files of this type`. That will make it open automatically in the program the file type has been associated with in Windows after it finishes downloading.